# C# WINFORMS - Making a button display a string variable from a class instantiation

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am making a basic text-based fighting game. I have a class called *move*. My class has a string variable called *DisplayName*. I have this code:

```
        try
        {
            m1.Text = playerMoves[0].displayName;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            m1.Visible = false;
        }
        try
        {
            m2.Text = playerMoves[1].displayName;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            m2.Visible = false;
        }
        try
        {
            m3.Text = playerMoves[2].displayName;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            m3.Visible = false;
        }
        try
        {
            m4.Text = playerMoves[3].displayName;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            m4.Visible = false;
        }
        try
        {
            m5.Text = playerMoves[4].displayName;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            m5.Visible = false;
        }
        try
        {
            m6.Text = playerMoves[5].displayName;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            m6.Visible = false;
        }
```

This code is in a button click-event that starts the battle. m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, and m6 are all buttons. They are all in a hidden panel that gets displayed before the code above is ran.

So, I have a List collection that holds instantiations of the class move. In my Form1_Load event, I load the user's moves from an XML File. I also have a class called *user*. It has the user's level and other stuff in it. Whenever you win a fight, you will earn a move depending on your level. It adds it to the playerMoves collection. 
But for some reason, it only displays the first button. If I walk through my code, it doesn't go into the catch, but it makes the second button (I am testing it with the second button) gets the DisplayName from playerMoves[1], but when my form comes back up after I finish walking through the code, it only displays the first button.
I have made sure that all the buttons are already visible before I run the code above, so can anyone explain to me what is wrong with my code? I am comepletely lost.

Comment: Why are you using multiple try and catch in your code

Comment: Because, the way I am doing it is a way of seeing if a move exists.

Comment: If I have only one move in playerMoves, than only one button will display. That is what all the try-catch's are doing.

Comment: set visible to true in try part.

Comment: If you try and it don't work let me know

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I didn't think of doing that because I have visible set to true on the form side!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that it is good approach to use try & catch. you can use if else condition like below. and considering all buttons are set visible to false by default.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(playerMoves[0].displayName)))    
           {
             m1.Text = playerMoves[0].displayName;
             m1.Visible=true;
           }
            else
           {
             m1.Visible=true;
           }
```

Comment: But why would I need to convert playerMoves[0].displayName to a string if it is already a string?

Comment: because it handles the null exception